# Pi 3 Bluetooth Software Requirements

Tags: pi-3, bluetooth, pulseaudio

I am using Minibian(a minimal Debian based OS), and trying to set up bluetooth so that I can stream audio to a bluetooth speaker from my Pi. What are the minimum packages I need to get bluetooth working?

Looking at the Official Raspbian image(which I was able to get the speaker to work with), I see these installed:

- `hcitool`
- `bluez`
- `firmware-brcm80211`
- `bluetoothctl`

I installed all these and I also installed blueman interface. I was able to successfully pair my device but when I try to connect it works for a second and then disconnects. It then will not connect again. I have pulseaudio installed already and the bluetooth module for it also. Thank you in advance.

**Update:** I noticed when I run `connect MAC` in bluetoothctl, where MAC is the BT address of the speaker, it fails; I then ran `cat /var/log/syslog` and it said:

```
bluetoothd[5556]: a2dp-sink profile connect failed for 00:1D:43:6D:03:26: Protocol not available
```

I searched that error and found an Arch Wiki and their suggestion was that either pulseaudio-bluetooth is not installed or pulseaudio needs to be restarted, or the module should be loaded with `pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover`. I already have the first installed, the second did not work, and the last gave access denied.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand where Minibian comes into the picture.  I think you are trying to stream audio from a Pi 3 to a bluetooth speaker.  Is that correct?  Are you saying that you are running "Minibian" on the Pi as opposed to Raspbian?

Comment: @Kolban Yes. And the reason I am saying that is to stress that it is very minimal unlike Raspbian where the software for doing that is already there.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error and solved as following:

```
$ sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
$ pulseaudio --start
$ bluetoothctl
$ connect @MACtoConnect
```